# any shortcut to get to design view of the form in visual studio 2010 winforms project/

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, visual-studio, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a shortcut to get to the designview form in a winforms project in visual studio 2010.
F7 will take you to code behind class form and shift + F7 will take you to design mode. Is there a shortcut to filename.designer.cs form
Where you have the control definitions, delegates (for click event etc). defined. I go to the form often if I change the name of click event etc.
I have to go through solution explorer and click on the file. Is there a shortcut like F7 that opens the designer.cs file?

Comment: You are not supposed to edit the file.  Microsoft providing a shortcut for something you are not supposed to do makes little sense.

Comment: I don't believe there's a way.

Answer (score 3):

Use F7 for switch between design view and code view

[For more info follow this link](http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/11/visual-studio-keyboard-shortcut-keys.html)

Comment: More specifically it is F7 to show code, shift-F7 to show designer, as shown at the link.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming C# Keyboard settings, the shortest way I know is press <kbd>F12</kbd> on `InitializeComponent()` to navigate to the .designer.cs *GUI creation* code.

If you're editing the names of control definitions, events and etc its much easier to use the Properties Window <kbd>F4</kbd>. Using the properties window does a great job of refactoring too.